# How to invert a Gaussian kernel

Tags: probability-theory

A problem I have to solve involves finding an explicit expression for the inverse of a Gaussian Kernel defined as $k(x,x’)=x\cdot x’$ where $x$ and $x’$ are elements of an $n$ dimensional vector space.

The kernel is over a multivariate Gaussian distribution P(X) and must satisfy
$$\int P(x’)k(x,x’)k^{-1}(x’,x’’) dx’= \delta(x-x’’)/P(x)$$

I don’t know how to find a closed form expression for k because it is supposed to be an integral form of a matrix inverse and all I can think of is writing out something which inevitably involves other matrix inverses, such as the inverse of the eigendecomposition.

I’ve looked at the inverse precision matrix given here https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_matrix but firstly I can’t see how it makes sense and secondly how it would be relevant to my problem.

Comment: Strange. 1) why don't you factorise out $P(x)$ in the integral? 2) using the right hand side the quantity $P(x)^2$ will appear. 3) after moving $P(x)$ from RHS to LHS, $\delta(x-x'')$ remains, thus the new LHS depends only on the difference $x-x''$ which seems impossible. 4) Finally an integral equal to a Dirac measure should be interpreted in terms of Fourier transform or of Schwartz distributions to make sense.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Pointing me in the direction of a Fourier transform, are you suggesting that I take the Fourier transform of both sides?

Comment: yes, if you have satisfactory answers to the strange things.